# XML Tag Prefixes Do Not Add Namespace to the XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I'm loading some XML which contains the following element:

```
<o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
</o:Security>
```

as follows:

```
 var doc = new XmlDocument(...);
```

I then proceed to create some elements and insert the in the `Security` element as follows:

```
var userNameTokenElement = doc.CreateElement( "o:UsernameToken" );
var userNameElement = doc.CreateElement( "o:Username" );
...
...
userNameTokenElement.AppendChild( userNameElement );
var securityElement = (XmlElement) doc.GetElementsByTagName("o:Security").Item(0);
securityElement.AppendChild( userNameTokenElement );
```

I then attempt to write the document to a stream as follows:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
doc.Save(stream);
```

but the `"o:"` part of the tag names aren't getting serialized.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the overloaded version which gets a namespace:

```
doc.CreateElement("o:Security", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")
```

Comment: See also http://www.w3.org/DOM/faq.html#create ... C# names the operation a bit differently, but the answer remains correct.